# Select image, which is in a div JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a selector in JQuery,

which selects me all `<img>` which are in a `<div>`.

So far so easy.

Now it comes to the hard point:

The image should  get selected if it is something like this:

```
<div> <img src="...">This image should get selected</img> </div>
```

or if it is something like this

```
<div>
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr> <img src=".."> and this image should get selected</img></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I do know that this kind of selecting an element should be avoided.

For my Use Case there is no other way.

Comment: what is the uniqueness we are talking about ? <img src = ".."> is that your search target ?

Comment: descendant selector `div img`

Comment: I believe your markup is invalid. _Permitted content: **None, it is an empty element**. / Tag omission: Must have a start tag and **must not have an end tag**._ [The HTML <img> Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: And the same here. _Permitted content: Zero or more **<td> or <th> elements**, or a mix of them._ [The HTML Table Row Element (<tr>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)

Comment: yeah, i saw that there are problems in the HTML i just wrote it down very fast, to explain my problem since the original code burns eyes---, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following selector will achieve what you want:

```
$('div img');
```

This will find all `<img />` elements inside `<div>`.

It's worth noting that your markup is invalid, though. `<img />` elements are self-closing, and `<tr>` elements must container a one or more `<td>` elements. You'll want to update your markup as follows:

```
<div> 
    <img src="..." title="This image should get selected" />
</div>
```

And similarly:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr> 
                <td><img src=".." title="and this image should get selected" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @C-linkNepal yes he did, but the parent `<table>` is wrapped inside a `<div>`, so the `<img />` is still a descendant of `<div>`.

Comment: @benM thanks, this did work out for me. i know that my html is wrong, just wrote it down fast do describe my use case :)) but hey cool that you pointed it out